# Launching ipython in emacs undesireably moves my windows

Tags: emacs, ipython

When I launch ipython in emacs, it rearranges all the windows. I find this annoying. Yet experimentation with my .emacs file yielded no solution. Where should I look? What should I suspect? What can I query?

Comment: How are you launching ipython?

Comment: In emacs, I use the ipython command to launch ipython and python-mode. In bash, I call ipython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python-mode.el the behaviour is controlled by customizable variable `py-split-window-on-execute`.

For changes on the fly exist commands `py-split-window-on-execute-off`, `py-split-window-on-execute-on`